# How to append values in list atomically (on exit) using context manager?

Tags: python, python-3.x, contextmanager

For starters, i'm newbee in Python.

I'm trying to write my own context manager, which'll append values to my list on exit. I created a copy of my list, but it seems this doesn't work properly.

**Here's my code:**

```
import time
import copy

a = [1,2,3]


class contextmanager():
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.abc = var

    def current(self):

        b.append(98325)



        return b

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print('Current list: {}'.format(self.current()))

with contextmanager(a) as t:
    time.sleep(1)
    b = copy.deepcopy(a)

    print("Changed list: {}".format(t.current()))
    time.sleep(2)
```

I want to add values on exit, like:

*current - [1,2,3]*

*append - [4,5,6]*

*before exit - [1,2,3]*

*exit - [1,2,3,4,5,6]*

but it doesn't work out that way and i got that:

*current - [1,2,3,4,5,6]*

*append - [4,5,6]*

*exit - [1,2,3,4,5,6,4,5,6]*

What am i doing wrong? How can i do that to fix it? I will be glad if you show me what i need to change in my code.

I don't seem to know Python that well yet..
Thanks for any of your help.

Comment: And i wanna ask how to use copy of the list properly? So i can save it and keep the set of my values and then append all of the values on exit? Can't find any information about that

Comment: You may ask a second question on list copy. you can either use the copy module or  copy = list[::]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the way you are suppose to use a context manager. First OO principles recommend to have proper encapsulation, which mean that the user should not have to know the implementation details.

I would propose the following design:

- the context manager take a list as its creation parameter
- it provides 2 methods:

  - `append(val)` which *prepares* appending val to the list and returns itself to allow chaining
  - `appending()` which returns the list of items to append
- the prepared items are appended only if no exception was raised

Possible implementation:

```
class contextmanager():
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.orig = var
        self.cur = []

    def append(self, val):
        self.cur.append(val)
        return self

    def appending(self):
        return self.cur

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if exc_type is None:
            self.orig.extend(self.cur)
```

Usage example:

```
a = [1,2,3]

print("initial", a)
with contextmanager(a) as t:
    t.append(4)
    print("appending", t.appending())
    t.append(5).append(6)
    print("appending", t.appending())

print("first pass", a)

try:
    with contextmanager(a) as t:
        t.append(7)
        t.append(8)
        print("appending", t.appending())
        raise Exception()
        t.append(9)
        print("appending", t.appending())
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception", e)

print("final", a)
```

which gives:

```
initial [1, 2, 3]
appending [4]
appending [4, 5, 6]
first pass [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
appending [7, 8]
Exception 
final [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: But i want to ask: if i want to use a copy of my list, how can i use it in this programm? I will be glad if you tell me.

Comment: The original list is referenced in the context manager as `self.orig`. If you want to expose it you could add a method close to that: `def orig(self, copy=False): return self.orig[:] if copy else self.orig`. `t.orig()` will return the original list and `t.orig(True)` will return a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Youre Code is append Twice.
Your first append is in the statement block of your Contextmanager (this Line: `print("Changed list: {}".format(t.current()))`)

Your second append is in the `__exit__` method which is called after the Contextmanager worked through its statement block.

Your Code works as follows:

create a and fill with 1,2,3
contextmanager starts work:
    -> deepcopy a to b
    -> first append through `t.current()`
    -> end of contextmanager -> call `__exit__` where the second append is.

hope it helps you understand it better.